# Optimally betting a beta-biased coin

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, game-theory

This question is inspired by [How to optimally bet on a biased coin?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464467/how-to-optimally-bet-on-a-biased-coin) by Nate River but generalized slightly. I decided the generalization might be interesting enough to be its own question.

A number $p$ is drawn from the interval $[0,1]$ according to a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha,\beta$, i.e. the probability density function is $\frac{ \Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{ \Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} p^{\alpha-1} (1-p)^{\beta-1}$. Everything after this is the same, so I'll just quote it:

> You are then given a biased coin that turns up heads with probability $p$, but the number $p$ is not known to you.
>
> You start with a total wealth of $1$ dollar. On each round, you may bet any amount $x$ from $0$ to your total wealth. The coin is flipped, and if it comes up heads you win $x$ dollars, otherwise you lose $x$ dollars.
>
> Given that there are $N \geq 2$ rounds in the game, what is the optimal strategy for the game? Here an optimal strategy will mean one that maximises the expected winnings.

The case $\alpha=\beta=1$ gives a uniform distribution which was the original question.

By linearity, the optimal bet is either all the money you have or none of it, except if these are equally profitable in which case any bet in between is also valid. So one may as well treat the game as one with a binary choice, either to bet everything or bet nothing.

Because the beta distribution is a conjugate prior, the state of information after multiple flips is given by another beta distribution: after $h$ heads and $t$ tails, the posterior distribution on $p$ is a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha+h, \beta+t$, and so can be viewed as another copy of the game with parameters $\alpha+h, \beta+t, N-h-t$.

So a strategy can be expressed as a set of parameters $\alpha, \beta, N$ where you bet it all and a complementary set where you bet nothing.

Probably it is not possible to give a useful exact formula for the boundary between these sets, so I'm most interested in an asymptotic for $\alpha, \beta, N$ large.

A regime that might be particularly tractable is $\alpha,\beta$ large with respect to both $\alpha-\beta$ and $N$. I think in this setting the cutoff may be given by an approximately linear relation in $N$, but I don't know the slope.

Comment: Can we get anything by writing down the optimal strategy via backward induction? E.g. we can define $f(h,t)$ to be the EV of betting at the current round $n = h+t$ given there have been $h$ heads and $t$ tails, followed by playing optimally thereafter; and $g(h,t)$ to be the EV of not betting and playing optimally thereafter; and $V(h,t) = \max\{f(h,t), g(h,t)\}$, and we can write $f(h,t)$ and $g(h,t)$ in terms of $V(h+1,t)$ and $V(h,t+1)$. Etc.

Comment: Another question is if we can prove monotonicity - if it is optimal to bet with $h$ heads and $t$ tails, is it optimal to bet with $h' \geq h$ heads and $t' \leq t$ tails?

Comment: This is really not my area, but it feels like it could be an application of the [Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) or other techniques in [Markov decision processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process). I only know about this pretty superficially so apologies if you've already seen and considered this.

Comment: @usul Certainly backwards induction works, the question is if one can turn that into some kind of reasonable closed form (at least approximately). The monotonicity question is a good one - it seems true and if true would simplify the backwards induction a bit (which I guess is why you proposed it).

Answer (score 3):

Next and let's hope final attempt, after numerous mistakes, a lot of nonsense, and an obscene number of edits: I think I have circumstantial evidence that things will just be very messy and the boundary of the betting region will not be linear in $N$ even in the asymptotic regime from the end of your post.

First of all, a simple observation: Whatever the optimal strategy is, it can never be right to bet and then wait on the next round after a H.

So once we start betting, in state $(N,\alpha,\beta)$, then the expectation is
$$
E(N,\alpha,\beta) = 2^N \int_0^1 p^N f_{\alpha,\beta}(p)\, dp = 2^N \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)\Gamma(\alpha+N)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+N)} ,
$$
or
$$
E(N,\alpha,\beta)=\prod_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{2(\alpha+k)}{(\alpha+\beta+k)} .
$$
(This is the same as flipping a coin with one fixed $p=p(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$ on each round and thus could probably have been written down directly.)
This is asymptotically
$$
E(N,\alpha,\beta)\simeq 1+\frac{N}{4\alpha}(N-1+2(\alpha-\beta))
$$
As already suggested in the comments, we can work our way backwards, starting at the end of the game. Obviously, when $N=1$, the correct strategy is to bet precisely when $\beta-\alpha<0$.

When $N=2$, we can consider betting only when $E>1$ (since we must keep betting) or $\beta-\alpha <1/2$, and obviously it is correct to bet when $\beta-\alpha<0$, so we can focus on $0<\beta-\alpha<1/2$. If we wait one round, the expectation is
$$
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}E(1,\alpha+1,\beta) + \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} = \frac{1}{2}E(2,\alpha,\beta) + \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} . \tag{1}
$$
This must be compared with $E(2,\alpha,\beta)$, and the result of this is that it is right to bet when $\beta-\alpha <1/3$. In particular, contrary to what I thought for a long time, it can be right to wait even though starting to bet now would also have made money (when $1/3<\beta-\alpha<1/2$).

For $N=3$, we can run a similar calculation, this time for $1/3<\beta-\alpha<1$ (it's clearly right to bet now if it was right for the same game with a smaller $N$, and the second bound comes again from the condition $E>1$). This is still manageable since if we don't bet and see a T, then there will be no further betting, and if there's an H, then $\beta -(\alpha+1)<0$, so we are (safely) in the betting region now. This means that if decide to wait on the first round, things don't branch further later. This will change when $N\ge 4$.

If I got the calculation right, it's now right to bet when $\beta-\alpha< 3/4$.

These three points $(N,\beta-\alpha) =(1,0), (2,1/3), (3,3/4)$ do not lie on a line.

By the way, a calculation similar to (1) works in general, and it shows the following: Suppose we are undecided between betting or waiting one round, but then betting in the case of an H. In other words, we are unsure about the right move, but we do assume we are close to the boundary, so it's a close call. Then the general version of (1), compared with $E(N,\alpha,\beta)$ shows that waiting is better precisely if it were right to bet on T this one round if allowed to do so and then continue the game according to the original rules.

Comment: For $N=2$, we can of course also find the boundary of the betting region exactly, and it's defined via an equation quadratic in $\alpha,\beta$, so this is already a bit on the messy side also.

Comment: That's roughly why I said approximately linear and not exactly linear...

Comment: @WillSawin: Fair enough, but even if it had been $(N,\beta-\alpha)=(1,0), (2,1/3), (3, 2/3), \ldots, $, that would have been approximately linear and not exactly linear since these values are correct only up to errors $O(1/\alpha^2)$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Maybe a reasonable question would be if the critical value of $\frac{\beta-\alpha}{N-1}$ is monotone (increasing?) in $N$ (eventually?). Obviously, it's between $0$ and $1/2$, and the first two values are $1/3$, $3/8$. I'm again not optimistic how tractable this is, but of course I've been wrong on so many things here already that my judgment should not be trusted. In any event, someone with better computer skills could probably easily produce a few extra values.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha_0$ bet the cutoff value of $\alpha$ as a function of $N$ and $\beta$ -- meaning that for $0<\alpha<\alpha_0$ it is better not to bet on the first coin flip while for $\alpha_0<\alpha$ it is better to bet on that first flip.

At fixed $N$ the graph of $\alpha_0$ as a function of $\beta$ has a neat asymptote with slope $1$. Its derivative $\text{d}\alpha_0/\text{d}\beta$ looks like a sigmoid. A close expression for $\alpha_0$ seems elusive, all the more as its second derivative looks like having at least $\frac{N}{2}-1$ discontinuities.

When $N\to+\infty$ and $\beta\to +\infty$ it then looks like $\alpha_0 = \beta−\frac{1}{2}N+c+O(\beta^{-1}N^{-1})$ with $c\approx1.095$ on the base of numerical evidence.

For example with $N=2000$ and $\beta=10^{20}$ we have $\alpha_0 = 10^{20}−1000 + 1.09478302041191816\dots$

At the other end when $\beta\to 0^{+}$ the cuttoff looks like occuring at $\alpha_0 = 2^{1−N}\beta + O(2^{-N}\beta^2)$.

Here is the PARI/GP code I used, à la Pascal's triangle :

```
shouldIbet(N,a,b)={
  my(P=vector(N+1,i,1), betting);
  forstep(n=N,1,-1,
    for(i=1,n,
      my(y=P[i]*(b+n-i), x=P[i+1]*(a+i-1));
      P[i]=if(betting=(x>y), 2*x, x+y);
  ) );
  betting
}

findcutoffa(N,b) = {
  my(a0=b/2, a2=b*2);
  while( shouldIbet(N,a0,b), a2=a0; a0/=2);
  while(!shouldIbet(N,a2,b), a0=a2; a2*=2);
  my(a, delta=(a2-a0)/2);
  while(delta>1e-20,
    a=a0+delta;
    if(shouldIbet(N,a,b), a2=a, a0=a);
    delta /= 2
  );
  a0+delta
}
```